# How to read in both Strings and Ints from a file, on seperate lines

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

so I have been searching your website and im still very unclear on how to do this, so let me try to explain this as best I can.

I have a input file like so:

```
2
Joe Flacco
1 3 5 6 7 8
Tom Brady
7 9 10 15 52 53
```

The first number is the number of "people" in the file, and the next is their first and last name. Next is 6 ints between [0,53] that are their "lottery" numbers. Anyways, I can get my code to pull in the first number, but getting theirs names and numbers is proving hard.

The last part, is getting it to fit in the struct we have declared (which we must use, that contains variables firstName[20] lastName[20] and numbers[6]. I know I am way off on how to do this all properly, but I am posting my code so you guys can see what Im doing. I appreicate any and all help. Also, Im trying to learn how to do it, not get you to right a program for me, so any explanations are very welcome.

```
for(int i=0; i < numPlays;i++)
{   
        char firstName[20];
        char lastName[20];
        for(int x=0; x<3;x++)
       fscanf(fr, "%c", &firstName[x]);
       for(int x=0; x<6;x++)
       fscanf(fr, "%c", lastName[x]);   
        for(int g=0; g<6; g++)
        {
        fscanf(fr, "%d", &Steve.numbers[g]);
        }
        temp[i]= Steve;
            //Tester code, lets hope this works
        for(int x=0; x<3;x++)
        printf("The persons name is %c.\n",&firstName[x]);
        //printf("The persons last name is %c.\n",temp[i].lastName);
}
```

Comment: For starters, you need to use `"%s"` to read *strings* using `fscanf` instead of reading character by character i.e. `fscanf(fr, "%s", lastName);` (Note no `&` or `[]` & no `for` loop). But safer to use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html). Also in `printf` to print char use `"%c"`, but dont pass address i.e. `printf("The persons name is %c.\n",firstName[x]);` or better to print string directly `printf("The persons name is %s.\n",firstName);`(w/o `for` loop). `NUL` termination of *strings* in C are a must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fgets` `strtok` and `atoi` will give you what you need. As for your program's structure, you probably want something like this:

```
typedef struct Player {
    char name[20];
    int numbers[6];
} Player;
#define SIZE(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

Player readplayer(){
      Player p;
      int x;
      char * num;
      //read a line with fgets;
      //memcpy() to p.name;
      //read another line
      for(num=strtok(line, " "),x=0;x<SIZE(p.numbers);x++, num=strtok(NULL," "))
          p.numbers[x] = atoi(num);
      return p;     
}

int main()
{
     //read a line with fgets
     int x, nplayers = atoi(line);
     Player *players = malloc(nplayers*sizeof(Player));
     for(x=0;x<nplayers;x++)
         players[x] = readplayer();
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it dave, but the one thing im confused on is, did you put both names (first and last) together? The struct i was given had to be with two different variables. This is the actual struct given to me.                                          typedef struct KnightsBallLottoPlayer 
{
char firstName[20];
char lastName[20];
int numbers[6];
} KBLottoPlayer;

Comment: I put both names together, but it should be trivial to separate them. Strtok splits a line into substrings, so where I say `memcpy to p.name`, just `strtok the line, memcpy to p.first. strtok again, and memcpy to p.last`

Answer (score 0):

you can use fgets() function for this purpose. it will read lines as String. after reading the numeric as string, just convert it to integer.

Comment: but how do i split up the "integer string" into the 6 different numbers. Later i have to compare them to 6 randomly generated winning numbers.

Comment: well you need to separate all the words/numbers & then by converting number to int you can do it. while converting, you need to check numeric using isNum() method. if it returns true then convert it to int.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate reading from a file and parsing the content i.e., define `readline()` and parse each line independently, [example](http://ideone.com/2VAh3).